# Netbeans 9.0 (Apache) doesn't open Netbeans 8.2 project folder

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-9

I installed Netbeans 9.0 from the Apache site and have installed Jave JDK 10.0.2. Netbeans launches but when I try to open an existing netbeans 8.2 project it does not recognize the project folders.

I can create a new project and a file folder structure is setup that looks the same as my 8.2 project and this can be opened okay. It's like the open project menu does not see a 8.2 project in the folder path.

added 9/6/18: The project is a simple windows GUI controlling a Labjack USB digital IO.

Comment: What type of 8.2 project are you trying to open? By default NetBeans 9.0 does not support web applications, so if you have not installed the necessary plugins I can understand that it might not recognize an 8.2 web application. But you should definitely be able to open a simple Java application created under 8.2 using NetBeans 9.0.

Comment: [1] What exactly is the _"simple windows GUI"_project? A JavaFX application? A Swing application? Something else? How was the project originally created?  [2] Also, could you check the NetBeans log (Views > IDE Log) and update your post if you see any messages/errors that might be relevant.

Comment: Try This solution https://sunilkanzar.wordpress.com/2018/08/02/plugin-set-up-in-netbeans-9-0/  , and then install `Java EE` plugin to available all Java ee project, and if your project is of gradle then install Gradle Support.

Answer (score 0):

I read this article on Apache NetBeans:

> So, does that mean that all the features that are not integrated into
>   Apache NetBeans (incubating) 9.0 cannot be used? No, it does not. Go
>   to Tools | Plugins in Apache NetBeans (incubating) 9.0 and, in the
>   Settings tab, register the NetBeans IDE 8.2 update center:
>
> http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz
>
> Then go to the Available Plugins tab and you'll see all the plugins
>   for NetBeans IDE 8.2., and search for the word "Kit", which will give
>   you bundles of modules, for higher-level features such as C/C++,
>   JavaScript, Groovy, PHP, and enterprise Java (i.e., Java EE or, as it
>   is known now, Jakarta EE).

That solution is on [Apache NetBeans](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/date/20180720).